# Searching for multiple parameters in URL using JQL

Tags: sql, search, jira, jql

I am new to Jira and am trying to understand JQL. I have been trying to figure out a way by which I can search for multiple parameters in a URL using the '%' wild card char using JQL.

So here's the sample JQL I am running in the advanced search section :-

> "Business Unit/Domain"  = "My Back Window" AND "PoC URL" ~ "%q=mm&start=%"

Now there are several URLs of the form

> http://www.myhouse.com/index/refine?q=mm&start=0;xyz

Now when I do the above JQL i get the above URL as the result. But if I change the JQL to something like :-

> "Business Unit/Domain"  = "My Back Window" AND "PoC URL" ~ "%q=mm%"

I do not get any results at all. Logically using the 'like(~)' operator and the wild card char, '%', in the above fashion should also give me the result that I received from the former JQL, right ?

I come from the SQL background and am trying to assume that JQL is quite similar to SQL, unless of course I am missing something.

> So what am I missing here ? Why don't I get the expected result and if this is the way JQL works then please advice a suitable work around for doing what is intended as indicated in the latter JQL. (That is searching for multiple parameters in a URL using ~ and % in JQL).

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using '%' character? This is a reserved character in JQL and you also do not need it - you can just type "q=mm&start="
"Business Unit/Domain" = "My Back Window" AND "PoC URL" ~ "q=mm"

There is also a bug which prevents searching for terms which contain special characters even if properly escaped
https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRA-25092

See this page for more information:
https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Performing+Text+Searches

Comment: thanks for the reply. Let me check if i am able to achieve what i want with just the above. But is it not that % is actually used as a wild card ?

Comment: Just try with and without % and you'll see that the result is the same. The only wildcard chars supported are *(multi char) and ?(single char)